# VBA Formatting Data with Split Function

Tags: excel, vba, split

I am trying to remove extraneous information from a column of data.

For example:

1 Data -> Data

2 Data -> Data

3 Data -> Data

Using split method I have done this, but it leave the extraneous data in another column. Since this will be used within a larger script, how can I simply remove the extra numbers without creating multiple columns?

Here is my code:

```
Dim splitVals As Variant
Dim totalVals As Long
Dim MyRange As Range

splitVals = Split(ActiveCell.Value, Chr(10))
totalVals = UBound(splitVals)
Range(Cells(ActiveCell.Row, ActiveCell.Column + 1), Cells(ActiveCell.Row, ActiveCell.Column + 1 + totalVals)).Value = splitVals
Range(Cells(ActiveCell.Row, ActiveCell.Column + 1), Cells(ActiveCell.Row, ActiveCell.Column + 1 + totalVals)).Copy
Range("A2").PasteSpecial Transpose:=True

Set MyRange = Range(Cells(ActiveCell.Row, ActiveCell.Column), Cells(ActiveCell.Row + 1 + totalVals, ActiveCell.Column))
MyRange.TextToColumns Destination:=MyRange.Offset(, 1), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
    TextQualifier:=xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=True, _
    Space:=True
```

Comment: How about you look for the first space (i assume spaces are your separator, as in your example(, then remove what is before it?

Comment: Side note: generally, it's preferable to avoid working with `ActiveCell`, and `Range(Cells(ActiveCell.Row, ActiveCell.Column + 1), Cells(ActiveCell.Row, ActiveCell.Column + 1 + totalVals))` can be simplified to `ActiveCell.Offset(,1)`.